# Map an array in a functional component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

```
function TypeArticleOne(props) {
let apiData = props.apiData;
const [ therapists, setTherapists ] = useState(apiData.topProfiles.therapists);
const [speciality, setSpeciality]= useState('ABA');
const [pageLoading, setPageLoading]= useState(true);

const topProfilesUrl = 'therapists/top/profiles'

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(speciality);
    getTopTherapists();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

}, []);

const getTopTherapists = () => {
    setPageLoading(true);
    loadTopTherapists();

};

const loadTopTherapists = () => {
    console.log("second");
    props.actions.reqGetTherapistsTopProfiles({
        body: {},
        headers: null,
        resource: `${topProfilesUrl}`
    })
};

useEffect(() => {

    if (apiData.topProfiles && apiData.topProfiles.success) {
        const therapistsLoad = apiData.topProfiles.therapists;
        setPageLoading(false);
        setTherapists([therapists].concat(therapistsLoad));
    }
    }, []);
```

How to map an array in a functional component? I want to map the therapists array from the functional component above.
I call the therapists in an array from an database and I need to map them to render in a card, inside an functional component.

```
const renderTherapists = (props) => {
    const items = props.therapists.map( (t, idx) => (
        <TherapistCard therapist={t} key={idx} />
    ))

    return (
        <div ref={0} className="therapist-list">
            { items }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You probably don't need the React Fragment as you already have a  as pointed out in the comments. Possibly the point on *destructuring* might still help.

**ORIGINAL:**

You might need to wrap the array in a **React Fragment** (`<>{array}</>`). This is required as you cannot directly return an array of components.

Also not sure what the structure of your `therapist` object is, but if you want to *destructure* it then it should be `({t, idx}) =>` instead of `(t, idx) =>` (add the curly braces).

```
const renderTherapists = (props) => {
    const items = props.therapists.map( ({t, idx}) => (
        <TherapistCard therapist={t} key={idx} />
    ))

    return (
        <div ref={0} className="therapist-list">
            <>
               { items }
            </>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is for **React 16.2.0** and later. See the blog post here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Comment: There's already a div surrounding the array of items, so a fragment is not required

Comment: Good point. I guess I'm not sure what the problem is then. I added a note on destructuring as it seemed like that wasn't being done right (but I might be missing something :-)

Comment: `I'm not sure what the problem is then` Yeah, i'm also unsure what info they need :)